# Whats really going on during an iOS App update?

Tags: ios, caching

I have a simple app that downloads some data from a webservice and displays it in tableviews.  In order to allow offline access, the app caches this data in the cache directory on the device itself.  I keep a list of all of the cached files for reference, and save that to the cache directory as well.  So after all of the downloads are complete I have the following files:

```
XMLFileList
XML1
XML2
...
```

I launched this app a couple weeks ago, and have since had to release a few minor updates as necessary to fix some minor bugs.  It seems, however, that when a user updates the app on their device, they no longer see the downloaded resources.  I have managed to get this to happen on a development device, by updating through the app store, then loading a debug build, and determined the following problem

It would seem that it is not displaying the data in the downloaded files because they no longer exist.  It is also not re-downloading the files because they show up in the saved list.  This provides a rather interesting question: why did the cached XML files get deleted, but not the master list?

What exactly is going on behind the scenes during an app update that I could account for, or reproduce to ensure this does not continue happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're putting files into /Library/Caches (or whatever it is), then there is no guarantee that those files will be there the next time you run your app. Anything you put into /Documents, however, will be there. And in fact, anything in /Documents will also be backed up to iCloud (unless you set the bit newly available in iOS 5.0.1 that lets you opt-out files in /Documents from being backed up.)

Anyway, the point is that you should read Apple's docs on what files you should put where. (I searched around for the correct reference unsuccessfully; I've seen it before though.) It boils down to this: Anything that is user generated should go in /Documents, anything that can be re-fetched from a server should go in /Library/Caches *and may be purged by the OS*.

Comment: Yeah, thats what I was afraid of.  Now how do I save it again so that only the app can access those files?

Comment: Put them in /Documents (and under iOS 5.0.1 perhaps mark them not to be backed up), or have your app able to re-download as needed.

Answer (score 0):

Cache directory contents are not guaranteed to be preserved.  But I don't see any documented guarantee that the entire directory will be cleared all at once.  (Maybe only the biggest and/or oldest contents or some such?)